# Cython function in pure python mode returning an list of strings

Tags: python, string, cython, bioinformatics, cythonize

I am trying to convert the following python function:

```
def python_compare(a: str, b: str) -> list:
    n = len(a)
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        letter1 = a[i]
        letter2 = b[i]
        
        if letter1 != letter2:
            mut = f'{letter1}{i}{letter2}'
            result.append(mut)
    return result


python_compare('aaa', 'aab')
output: ['a2b']
```

To a cython function written in pure python mode.

I am running the code in a jupyter notebook, hence the `%%cython` line. This is what I am trying:

```
%%cython -a

import cython

@cython.cfunc
def compare(a: cython.basestring, b: cython.basestring) -> cython.array:
    
    n = cython.int = len(a)
    i: cython.int
    letter1: cython.basestring
    letter2: cython.basestring
    mut: cython.basestring
    result: cython.array(cython.basestring, n)
    
    for i in range(n):
        letter1 = a[i]
        letter2 = b[i]
        
        if letter1 != letter2:
            mut = f'{letter1}{i}{letter2}'
            result.append(mut)
    return result
```

However, this gives me the output:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

import cython

@cython.cfunc
def compare(a: cython.basestring, b: cython.basestring) -> cython.array:
                                                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

8a1.pyx:5:65: Not a type

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

import cython

@cython.cfunc
def compare(a: cython.basestring, b: cython.basestring) -> cython.array:
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

8a1.pyx:5:21: 'basestring' not a valid cython attribute or is being used incorrectly

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

import cython

@cython.cfunc
def compare(a: cython.basestring, b: cython.basestring) -> cython.array:
                                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

8a1.pyx:5:43: 'basestring' not a valid cython attribute or is being used incorrectly

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        letter1 = a[i]
        letter2 = b[i]
        
        if letter1 != letter2:
            mut = f'{letter1}{i}{letter2}'
            result.append(mut)
           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

8a1.pyx:20:12: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        letter2 = b[i]
        
        if letter1 != letter2:
            mut = f'{letter1}{i}{letter2}'
            result.append(mut)
    return result
          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

8a1.pyx:21:11: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

Can someone help me to rewrite the function in cythons pure python mode so that it compiles and works?

All advices and comments are much appreciated!
Thanks,

William

Comment: Why not `@cython.cfunc def compare(a: str, b: str) -> list:`? i.e. use the types you actually want

Comment: I tried that, but it does not accept a python object as a return type...

Comment: I'd make sure you're using the Cython 3 alpha (instead of Cython 0.29.x) - that's made some significant improvements to typing from annotations. Failing that, if you don't specify the return type it'll default to "generic Python object". Practically there isn't a huge difference between having a list return type and a generic Python object return type

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Cython expert, but it seems that you do not create your `result` array prior to trying to append something to it (The error message is a strong hint: "local variable 'result' referenced before assignment").
It seems that you only declare its type (`result: cython.array(cython.basestring, n)`), and then do not assign anything to this variable before trying to append.

By the way, is it really possible to `append` to an array? You declare something of a certain size (`n`). Is `append` supposed to increase the size of this array? If not, where in the array the data is supposed to be inserted?

In your plain Python code, you start with an empty list. Then you append things to the end. This looks OK, but may not be translated literally in Cython using an array.

My intuition of non-Cython expert is that instead of appending to the array, you should modify values in-place (C-style), and for that, you need an index. Could your loop variable `i` play this role?